# Yii2 - best way to handle models over different APIs

Tags: serialization, yii2

I'm getting some products info from 2 APIs (considering to add third one). My app has module which contains interfaces (to be implemented in main app) like this:

```
interface ProductInterface
{
    public function getId();

    public function getSku();

    /** @return GalleryImageInterface[] */
    public function getImages();

    ...
}
```

```
interface GalleryImageInterface
{
    public function getId();

    public function getUrl();

    ...
}
```

The goal is to handle API data in the correct way to create list of products implementing these interfaces. The simplest way I found is to get API's json data in my frontend controller, json_decode() it to array and then map those arrays to module's models, field by field with relations.
But it seems to be little harmful if I want to add some extra fields from API or add another API as source.

I will be very grateful to get some tips from experienced Yii2 developers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead interfaces, I'll use Model, to get advantages from massive assignment.
Then, I'll get these attributes in static method, so you have an unique point of access when you want to import data.

**Product class**

```
use yii\base\Model;
class Product extends Model
{
      $id;
      $sku;
      $images;

      public static parseFromItemArray($ia) {
          $obj = new self();
          $obj->attributes = $ia;
          $obj->images = GalleryImage::parseFromListArray($ia['images'];

          return $obj;
      }

      public static parseFromListArray($la) {
          $output = [];
          foreach($la as $li)
          {
              $output[] = self::parseFromItemArray($ia);
          }
          return $output;
      }           
}
```

**GalleryImage class**

```
use yii\base\Model;
class GalleryImage extends Model
{
      $id;
      $url;

      public static parseFromItemArray($ia) {
          $obj = new self();
          $obj->attributes = $ia;

          return $obj;
      }

      public static parseFromListArray($la) {
          $output = [];
          foreach($la as $li)
          {
              $output[] = self::parseFromItemArray($ia);
          }
          return $output;
      } 
}
```

When you get json data from api, you can import in this way:

```
// $jsonString is data from api
// I'll use json_encode second parameter to specify that I want and associative array and not an object
// jsonData = json_encode($jsonString, true);

$products = Product::parseFromItemArray($jsonData);
```

It could be a good think to put parseFromListArray in shared model so you have not to rewrite everytime for every model.

Also, in this way you have the full control of import data method and it is enought add new member in classes to add new property to import.